# CD/DVD Drive not working 13.04

Tags: 13.04, drive

CD/DVD Drive is not working. Non of the all fixes from here work for me. 
Devices menu does not contain a CD/DVD Drive. Few days ago it worked just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Are you sure it's not a hardware problem? Maybe a cable came loose?

Answer (score 0):

The cd drive probably doesn't have Linux support.  You can try to install the windows version of the drivers though.